# How can I add an extension to my chromedriver at the Robot level with Selenium2Library

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, robotframework, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to instantiate a chromedriver instance in my Robot suite setup but I need to install an extension upon browser startup. I'm able to easily do this at the Python level by simply adding chromeoptions to my webdriver instatiation, but I need to do this at the Robot level. I found that there IS a keyword "Create Webdriver" that allows you to pass arguments into your webdriver instantiation. However, I still cannot get an extension to install at startup. I am using Options from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options and the function add_extension. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
Some_Setup
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()       sys, selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
    ${options.add_extension}=        Set_Variable          path/to/extension
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

If there is a way to pass in my extension via desired capabilities, how would I format that in a dictionary? It seems like desired_capabilties has a chromeOptions field with an args:[] and extensions:[] fields avaialable but I don't know how to pass my extension to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Options from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options, add the extension in Python using

```
options = Options()
options.add_extension(path-to-extension)
```

return the Options object, save it into the ${chrome_options} variable, and then...

```
${kwargs}=          Create Dictionary        chrome_options=${chrome_options}
Create Webdriver    Chrome                   kwargs=${kwargs}
```

Note the the robot test suite must import the python lib that defines some "get_options" function as above.