# How can I add a Chrome extension with in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to load a chrome extension using Robot Framework and SeleniumLibrary, I've looked at other examples posted on Stack Overflow but none seem to be working for me. From my reading of the `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options` docs I should be able to pass the following option `add_extension(argument)` however when attempting to do so I see that my extension is present in the browser but not enabled/activated. Is this not possible purely with only Robot Framework?

Would loading via Python be best?

I've referenced the articles below:
[How can I add an extension to my chromedriver at the Robot level with Selenium2Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772692/how-can-i-add-an-extension-to-my-chromedriver-at-the-robot-level-with-selenium2l)

[How can I add an extension to my chromedriver at the Robot Framework with Selenium2Library and launch remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693822/how-can-i-add-an-extension-to-my-chromedriver-at-the-robot-framework-with-seleni#34721818)

Comment: I have the same question, I need robot framework to have interaction with Chrome Extension to complete 2fa authentication, have you been able to find the answers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Download one of version ChromeDriver 
  https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- Extract to chromedriver.exe desktop
- Move to chromedriver.exe , where is the your project is exist. (e.g Python\Python37 here)
- Be sure that your folder *Python37* of path is added where is the Properties --> Advanced --> Environment Variables --> Edit environment variable . If its not added , you should add new one.
- Then Try to execute your script.
- I added u a script example down ;

  *** Settings ***
  Documentation  Anasayfa Test Senaryoları
  Library  Selenium2Library

  *** Test Cases ***
  Test Senaryosu yeni

  ```
  Open Browser  https://www.kariyer.net/  chrome
  Close Browser
  ```

Then it should work with chrome driver.

Comment: How would this be different than from what I am executing now? Wouldn't Chrome run in automation mode once the script executes? In which case the extension would be removed from Chrome in automation mode, unless I am missing something.